# Iterate using a variable as the loop interval

Tags: matlab

I have the following variable:

```
framespan = '83:89'; %type is char
```

I want to have a for that would look like:

```
for i = framespan
%code
end
```

I'm not looking for the 'for' loop to have that specific structure, I just want to iterate throught that interval.

Basically I have a big file from where i get the framespan, the problem is that i can get it only as char since i get it from an XML file.

How can I achieve this in Matlab?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it safely, and you *should* want to do it safely, you should parse the char arrays yourself (using something like [`strsplit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) or [`split`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/split.html) using newer MATLABs):

```
framespan = '83:89'; %type is char 
nums = strsplit(framespan,':');
% TODO: handle problematic inputs
from = str2double(nums{1});
to = str2double(nums{2});
for k=from:to
   ...
end
```

---

The reason I mentioned safety is that the straightforward/naive approach would be to use `str2num`, that can directly transform your string to a range. But that's the problem: the documentation states that it uses `eval` under the hood, and it will gladly execute malicious code for you in case somebody can inject hostile code into what you read into `framespan`. This is why I very strongly suggest parsing the string yourself, considering the very well-defined format you have.

Comment: Hi, I'm geting the following error when using the split function : Undefined function 'split' for input arguments of type 'char'. Any solution. Thank you!

Comment: @AMayer I updated with an older function called `strsplit` (and fixed another syntax error in the mean time), try the current version please.

Comment: @AMayer I'm glad it did:) I added a note about safety, which is the primary reason I wanted to add this answer. I suggest that you read it, because it's not widely known that `str2num` is unsafe.